# Make variable substitution in string

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I define a json file:

> `foo.json`:

```
{"key":"${VALUE}"}
```

> makefile:

```
export VALUE=bar
SHELL=/usr/bin/env bash
foo=$(shell cat foo.json)

bar:
    @echo "$(foo)"
```

The question is: how do I variable expand `${VALUE}` via make's variable substitution or `echo`'s BASH substitution such that double quotes in the valid JSON file are preserved on **OUTPUT** (yes make preserves them, and yes, `echo $(foo)` also evaluates the variables -- but drops the double quotes -- and yes, I do not care about newlines getting dropped)?

As to the why of it all, suppose I have a routine that expects an expressive JSON file that amounts to a language (rather than a config), and I am using Make to control the system:

```
.PHONY: generator

# in the language of control theory
generator: $(foreach q,${Qm},.Qmarked-startup-$q)
    application $@ -i <(pseudo code: {envsubst $@.json})

.Qmarked-startup-%: $(pseudo code: q0 dependencies ... )
    # $* here is a verb
    application $* -i <(pseudo code: {envsubst $*.json})
```

Comment: Exactly what do you want that makefile to print?

Comment: It would be better if you showed us what you really wanted to do.  It's unlikely that this (using `$(shell ...)`) will do what you really want to do, because it always throws away all newlines (for example).  If we knew what you really were trying to achieve, rather than `echo ...`, there are probably better ways to do it.

Comment: @MadScientist edited and updated.

Comment: It would be more clear that you don't care about newlines if you didn't have the comment `// foo.json` in your example... if you have that then your entire JSON file will be commented out when newlines are removed...

Comment: @MadScientist that comment is to indicate that the context of the markdown is in the file foo.json.

Comment: @MadScientist updated for more clarity as to exactly what is going on.  `envsubst` seems like the clue I was looking for, but what I was going for, in an ideal world, is to leverage Make so that it processed the file as if it were copied and pasted into the variable assignment

Comment: If that's what you want, then why did you accept the envsubst solution instead of HardcoreHenry's solution which does _exactly that_?  However I'm glad you got something working.

Comment: @MadScientist I'll check out both.  I like envsubst because it is constrained explicitly to env substitution rather than an eval expression.

Comment: Perhaps there's a misunderstanding: we're talking about the **make** `eval` function here, not the shell's `eval` command.  See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this Makefile :

```
export VALUE=bar
SHELL=/usr/bin/env bash
foo=$(shell cat foo.json)

bar:
    $(warning $(foo))
```

You can see $(foo) does contain double quotes. But $VALUE is not expanded.

You can try this :

```
export VALUE=bar
SHELL=/usr/bin/env bash
foo=$(shell VALUE=$(VALUE) envsubst < foo.json)

bar:
    @echo '${foo}'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to expand variables from Make's environment, you can use `eval` to expand the variables inside of an assignment.

Assuming you don't mind catinating all the lines together as per @MadScientists's comment, you could grep out the comments and combine the json into one line as follows:

```
export VALUE:=bar

foo:=$(shell grep -v "^\S*//" foo.json)
$(info foo=[$(foo)])

$(eval foo2:=$(shell grep -v "^\S*//" foo.json))
$(info foo2=[$(foo2)])

bar:
        @echo "from recipe: foo2=[$(subst ",\",$(foo2))]"
```

The `$(subst ",\",...)` escapes the quotes before sending to bash.    This outputs:

```
foo=[{"key":"${VALUE}"}]
foo2=[{"key":"bar"}]
from recipe: foo2=[{"key":"bar"}]
```

Note: security consideration -- if an outsider has access to foo.json, then they could make make run whatever they wanted with the maker's privileges.

Comment: I don't think you need the `$(subst ...)` in the recipe.  Just put the echo in single quotes, that way the shell won't mess with the contents: `@echo 'from recipe: foo2=[$(foo2)]'`

Comment: Also I think you can ignore the comments: the OP probably doesn't actually have any in their environment.  I think it is as simple as just: `$(eval foo = $(shell cat foo.json))` (or you can use `:=` if you want simple expansion of `foo` if you prefer)